Why Does Current Flow Through the Neutral in a Wye Transformer Secondary?

I'm trying to understand the behavior of current in the neutral wire of a wye (Y) transformer secondary (EU residential wiring). Specifically, I'm curious about the following points:

Does the current flow back into the neutral wire in a wye transformer secondary?

Isn't the current in the neutral supposed to be zero in a wye transformer?

If the current doesn't flow back into the neutral, where does it loop back in the circuit?
When I asked my professor they insisted that the current in the neutral must remain 0 or the transformer will fail, but they failed to answer my question.


I've attached a diagram to illustrate my understanding. In the diagram, a load RR is connected across one of the phases and the neutral. If there is an imbalance in the system, how does the current behave, and what role does the neutral wire play in this scenario?
Thanks for your help!

You have not drawn a balanced condition.

The question wasnt meant for balanced conditions but for residential wiring (which is inherently unbalanced), sorry for the confusion.


Does the current flow back into the neutral wire in a wye transformer secondary?

In an unbalanced three-phase transformer (the situation your describing) current will flow THROUGH the neutral wire. When all phases are balanced, the neutral doesn't carry any current. In theory, it can be removed completely from the circuit without any adverse effects in this case.

Isn't the current in the neutral supposed to be zero in a wye transformer?

There is no requirement that the current has to be zero in the neutral. If that were true there wouldn't be a need for a neutral wire. Only under the particular balanced case where all phases have equal current will there be no current flowing in the neutral.

If the current doesn't flow back into the neutral, where does it loop back in the circuit? When I asked my professor they insisted that the current in the neutral must remain 0 or the transformer will fail, but they failed to answer my question.

Current will flow to and from the other phases. Consider a simpler single phase configuration: 2 hot phases 180 degrees apart. Even though we're using 2 phases, this is still a single phase system. You can consider the complementary phase as the return path of current for half the cycle. Then, the roles reverse for the second half. In effect, the opposite phase is serving the purpose of the neutral. For the 3 phase condition, the idea is the same. But this time one phase is balancing out the other 2 phases. So on average, the net current sum is zero of all 3 phases.
The part about "When I asked my professor they insisted that the current in the neutral must remain 0 or the transformer will fail" is nonsense or an appreciable misunderstanding. This is simply not true. The closest way I can interpret this to make this "true" is if your professor meant the voltage is 0V with respect to ground which is typically the case (or at least an ideal design goal). Transformers are designed with neutrals (sometimes called "center taps" in split-phase systems) for this very reason.


Yes.

Only if it's balanced.

There isn't any other path for the return current. The neutral carries it.


